# Which fingering to use for this section of a song

Tags: guitar, fingering, fingerstyle-guitar

I can’t figure out the best fingering for this part of Sound of Silence. What should I do?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, do you know what 2/3CIII and 1/2CV mean? They're there to guide people like yourself who need help working out which fingers to use.

Let's take 2/3CIII. it represents a barre of 4 out of the 6 strings (2/3) as a barre. while III means do that on fret 3, with the usual index finger. That will allow the notes on the fourth and second strings to be in the right place. Leaving the remaining fingers to fret on 5 and 7 as you want. Although it's quite a stretch to reach fret 7 at the bar's end. Maybe leave that note as one on its own, as the whole hand moves up the the next bar's position.

1/2CV is a bit different, as there appears to be a barre on fret 5, looking after, basically, the 3rd string. That'll be with the index finger again, ring finger on first fret 7. Again pinky will play top string notes, and again, the last note (on the top string), will be played as an individual as the hand moves to the next bar's position - which we really need to see, to complete the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Tim. I did not know what 2/3CIII and 1/2CV mean and honestly didn't even notice them, so I'm glad you pointed them out. This is helpful. And, to address your last point, the next bar begins in first position.